# iPhone objective c how to choose which view controller to load at app start

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, xcode-storyboard, rootview

I know there are quite a few threads about that topic, and I tried every single option. But nothing works.

So, here what I have, a loginviewcontroller and a tabbarviewcontroller. If the device is already registered, the tabbar should appear, if not the loginview. I have the tabbarviewcontoller as initial view controller in storyboard. This works if the device is registered.
This is what I basically do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

//define viewcontroller
LoginViewController *loginviewcontroller = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];

//check if device id in coredata
NSString *deviceId = [self retrieveFromUserDefaults:cKey_DeviceId];
if(deviceId == nil){
    NSLog(@"device not registered");
    [self.window setRootViewController:loginviewcontroller];
    [self.window addSubview:loginviewcontroller.view];
}

//show them
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

I have a NSlog output in my loginview viewdidload method, so  I know, that the loginview is loaded. But the screen is black!!! I dont know why. The viewcontroller runs the viewdidload method, but there is just no screen output.

What do I do wrong???

thanks
dominik

Comment: NSLog(@"device not registered"); did you get this in the log ?

Comment: Do you definitely have `window` wired up? If you `NSLog(@"%@", self.window)` then do you get meaningful output?

Comment: yeah, I get the log "device not registered" !!

Comment: this is the output from NSLog(@"%@", self.window)    <UIWindow: 0x8e970d0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); hidden = YES; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8e956e0>>

Comment: what is the output of NSLog(@"%@", loginViewController);? i'm wondering what is it's frame set to.

Comment: output of     NSLog(@"%@", loginViewController); => <LoginViewController: 0x75c2830>

Answer (score 0):

If LoginViewController has a .xib file, you're calling the wrong init method. You want the initWithNibName:bundle: method.

Also, you do not need to call `[self.window addSubview:loginviewcontroller.view];` after you set the root view controller.

And if the deviceId is NOT null, then you will get a blank screen.

And loginviewcontroller is leaking memory. You should release it after setting it to the root view controller.

Comment: Hi, I am working with stroyboard, so there is no .xib file just for loginviewcontroller. The weired thing is, that this is not the first app where I want similar thing. Last time with ios4 and without storyboard was it way easier.

Comment: BTW: ios4.2 with sdk5 does not allow to release because of ARC, though.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases using a password, I've found it's best to load the initial (already logged in) screen, then check to see if a login is needed.  If it is, immediately put up a login screen as a modal view.  Launch the login screen from viewDidLoad in your initial screen.

Comment: good idea, I will try it tomorrow, thanks. Sometimes when you are so "in" a problem you just don't see something else ;)

Comment: which method would be the best to pop the modal view up? viewdidload or viewwillapear? or any other suggestons?

Comment: The call you're looking for is presentModalViewController: animated:

Comment: Hi, yeah sure. I ment the in which method should I call presentModalviewContoller, did it in viewdidload. And I thought it worked, but at the moment the loginview never pops up. @OwenHartnett

Comment: if(!([deviceId length] > 0)){
        NSLog(@"device not registered");
        [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES]; 
    }   and of course I get the output "device not registered"

Comment: Don't call it from your tabBarController.  Call it from your top most view or navigation controller, if you have one.

Comment: Load your viewController for the first Tab item.  Call your modal controller after that's loaded, when it's done it'll fall back to your first tab item.

Comment: That is, load the first tab item's viewController when you start.  Using that view, call [firstViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES]

Comment: ok, made it. so much thx. solved it by sorted the loginview out of the storyboard and created a extra nib file for the loginview.

Comment: It's considered good form to close off the question by indicating the answer.